# Applying CSS styling with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

In Site.css I have this:

```
tr {
background-color: #fff;
}
.alt {
background-color: #ccc;
}
```

And in my view I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('tr:even').addClass('alt');
});


<h2>Shakespeare's Plays</h2>
<table>

<tr >
<td>As You Like It</td>
<td>Comedy</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>All's Well that Ends Well</td>
<td>Comedy</td>
<td>1601</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

But I am getting no styling in my even rows... All look the same thing....
I already installed the jquery Package in my project

Comment: You say you installed the jQuery package, but are you including it in your page anywhere?  Because your code as posted should work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYtNX/1/)

Comment: @jmoerdyk: It should, but does not work for jQuery 2.0.0b3

Comment: @jmoerdyk 
You are right....
I had to add this:
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko That's a problem on jsfiddle. Jsfiddle is referencing `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0b3.js`, which returns 404.

Comment: "jQuery 2.0 has the same API as jQuery 1.9, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8."
--> Why would you use it ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are including jQuery in your page. Add the following before your script in your head:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Or at the end of your <body> !